# Which built in AudioUnit can resample audio?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I have an application that will need to rapidly change the sample rate of audio.

The pitch shift caused by doing simple linear interpolation of the samples is totally fine.

Is there an audio unit that resamples in software in real time (ie: does not need to change the hardware sample rate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Apple's AU `kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter`, `kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter` can do this.  Internally the AU contains a `FormatConverter` that performs the work.